# Помогите мне объяснить кнопке, что она должна определить своего "родителя"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

У меня есть ListView который создается по классу в ObservableCollection

```
public class ImageClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Коллекция: `PhotoList = new ObservableCollection<ImageClass>();` 
Ну и собственно заполнение: `ImageList.ItemsSource = PhotoList;`

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ImageList" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,9">
     <Image Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50" Background="#FFC2C9D0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <RadioButton GroupName="State" FontSize="25" Content="-"  />
      <RadioButton GroupName="State" FontSize="25" Content="+;"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
      </StackPanel>
     </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я никак не могу придумать, как сделать, чтобы по нажатию RadioButton + или - эти данные как нибудь сохранялись (например в классе где лежит ссылка на изображение) И при повторном построении элементов ListView (например после перемещений по страницам приложения) по этому классу все выбранные RadioButton были в таком же нажатом положении. Основная трудность - это как RadioButton записать данные в нужный из много созданных ImageClass.
Натолкните пожалуйста на мысль :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо двух радиобаттонов можно использовать чекбокс и в модели коллекции добавить поле bool IsChecked, в которое сохранять значение чекбокса. Ну или если так нужны радиобаттоны, то сделать по аналогии.

Comment: Но у меня создается же под каждую картинку, как я понимаю, свой класс. И сама трудность это объяснить кнопке что она изменять это поле именно в том классе, в котором находится картинка выше

Comment: В PhotoList  у вас хранится коллекция всех картинок с id. Добавьте в ImageClass еще одно свойство, которое будет отвечать за состояние кнопки. Потом сделайте двунаправленную привязку чекбокса к этому свойству и всё.

Comment: Сейчас попробую...)

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо)